# I want to connect to my router through wifi and use its pstn phone line

Tags: router, modem, voip

Can anyone refer me where to look I want when I am not at home to connect to my router and use it to call through my phone line (so when I am out of the country I will pay local price to place calls through wifi)?

My router is a Thompson tg782i.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this.

The "Phone 1" and "Phone 2" ports are for you to connect analogue (POTS) handsets which can be used either for VOIP calls or for POTS calls via the analogue "PSTN" port.

Using VOIP software on a PC attached to the LAN ports you can make VOIP calls - these are not routed out the PSTN port.

There's nothing to suggest the 782 can act as a VOIP to PSTN gateway.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Not exactly the way you describe anyway. Your router, regardless of the type of internet connection you have, has no visibility into your PSTN line, even if it is a lineshare ADSL connection into a modem/router combo. As far as that router is concerned, it is Ethernet protocol up until it hits the modem, and then it is ATM protocol up until it hits the DSLAM. The connection over the phone line is ATM and is at a much higher frequency than phone calls use. In other words, it is designed so that it does not interfere and therefore does not even know if/when the phone line is in use. This especially so if you have a dry loop for your ADSL as the phone would go through a completely different line. And again, even more so if you have a cable, or other type of connection as they aren't even using the phone lines.

You can always setup a VoIP connection with a softphone through a VoIP service, VPN into your netowrk, and run the softphone through your connection (The reason I suggest VPN with a softphone is because you never know quite what ports will be blocked on any given connection that will render your VoIP useless, but if your network is set up for it, when you VPN in, you ensure it will always work). This however might cause audio issues when latency issues occur on either connection.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the cheapest PC ([Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/)?) that can handle a (USB?) modem and hook that up to your router and its phone jack, then install some [remote admin software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_administration) on that and connect to it via the router.